# Detecting for boolean items and changing them in jQuery

Tags: jquery, boolean

I want to highlight some items that have the value **true**.
Here is the code

```
    $('td.obsolete').each(function(index) {
        alert($(this).text());
        var val = $(this).text();
        alert("val:" + val);
        if (val === true) {
            alert("now then");
            $("td.obsolete").css('background-color', '#fef1f8');
        }
    });
```

The first 2 alerts work and return False and True as expected when that item is found in the td cell.
The 3rd alert "now then" never gets fired.
I have tried

```
       if (val === true) 
if (val == true)
if (val == 'True')
```

Any clues?

Comment: Well, the string `"True"` is not the same as the boolean `true`. `if (val == 'True')` should work though: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/3cehT/ Make sure you remove every leading and trailing white space from the string.

Comment: what values are you putting inside the td? and did you check for case sensitivity? maybe you want to try .toLowerCase() comparison?

Comment: Figured it out - I needed to do this:   val = jQuery.trim(val);
I think there was a carriage return or spaces inside the table cell.

Comment: You can answer your own question ;) Also make sure that you call  `$(this).css('background-color', '#fef1f8');`, otherwise every of these cells get the background color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $('td.obsolete').each(function(index) {
        alert($(this).text());
        var val = $.trim($(this).text()).toLowerCase();
        alert("val:" + val);
        if (val == 'true') {
            alert("now then");
            $("td.obsolete").css('background-color', '#fef1f8');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('document').ready(
    function(){
        $('td.obsolete').each(function(index) {
        alert($(this).text());
        var val = $(this).text();
        alert("val:" + val);
        if (val == 'true') {
            alert("now then");
            $("td.obsolete").css('background-color', '#fef1f8');
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Zah4z/

If you have spaces in your td text then you can check them with `jQuery.trim();`

this is what i tried and its working fiddle link provided

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('td.obsolete').each(function(index) {            
        var val = $(this).text();
        val = jQuery.trim(val);            
        if (val != 'False') {
            $(this).css('background-color', '#dfc4cc');                
                var previous = $(this).prev();   
                previous.css('background-color', '#dfc4cc');                
        }   
    });    
});
```

Values needed trimming! Here I am also highlighting the previous table cell.